# Solr highlighting text in &trade; while searching for "trade"

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

In my application, when I search for keyword "trade", Solr highlighting this text in HTML special char '&trade;'.

Example:
Text before highlight: Samsung Galaxy&trade; S4
Text after highlight: Samsung Galaxy&<em>trade</em>; S4

How to avoid this problem and also I don't' want to index this text in case of '™'.

Please suggest me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Can you skip indexing '™' altogether by any chance?